# Converting text to decimal quantities, handling '3 and a half' scenario

Tags: python

This code should convert text to decimals.
If I write "three" it converts it to 3, but the issue is when I write "three and half".

Is there is any solution for this case?

Example:

```
"Please get me a three and half of tomato and one bottle of milk, 3 kilos of 
caroots and and half kilo of beans finally 1 bottle  water, thank you"
```

Result:

```
Shopping list:
1 bottle milk
3.0 kilo carrots
0.5 kilo tomato
1.0 bottle water
0.5 kilo beans
```

Results should be:

```
Shopping list:
1 bottle milk
3.0 kilo carrots
3.5 kilo tomato
1.0 bottle water
0.5 kilo beans
```

```
import re
from collections import OrderedDict

products = {
    "milk": ["milk"],
    "carrots": ["carrot", "carrots"],
    "tomato": ["tomato", "tomatoes"],
    "water": ["water"],
    "beans": ["beans"]
    # Add more products in a similar manner
}

def convert_to_decimal(quantity_text):
    quantity_text = quantity_text.lower()
    if quantity_text in ['half', 'quarter']:
        return {'half': 0.5, 'quarter': 0.25}[quantity_text]
    elif quantity_text.isdigit():
        return float(quantity_text)
    else:
        words_to_numbers = {
            'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4, 'five': 5,
            'six': 6, 'seven': 7, 'eight': 8, 'nine': 9, 'ten': 10
        }
        return words_to_numbers.get(quantity_text, 0.0)

def create_shopping_list(text):
    items = OrderedDict()
    for product, keywords in products.items():
        for keyword in keywords:
            pattern = fr'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\b(?:half|quarter|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten)\b)\s*(?:bottle|kilo)?s?\s*(?:of\s*)?{keyword}'
            matches = re.findall(pattern, text, re.IGNORECASE)
            for match in matches:
                quantity = convert_to_decimal(match)
                items.setdefault(product, set()).add(quantity)  # Storing quantities in a set to remove duplicates

    result = []
    for product, quantities in items.items():
        for quantity in quantities:
            # Include the unit based on the product type
            if product == 'water':
                unit = 'bottle'
            else:
                unit = 'bottle' if product in ['milk'] else 'kilo'
            result.append(f"{quantity} {unit} {product}")

    # Convert the result back to a list to preserve the order and remove duplicates
    unique_shopping_list = list(dict.fromkeys(result))
    return unique_shopping_list

# Example usage
user_input = "Please get me three and half kilo of tomato and one bottle of milk, 3 kilos of carrotssn and and half kilo of beans finally 1 bottle  water, thank you"
shopping_list = create_shopping_list(user_input)
if shopping_list:
    print("Shopping list:")
    for item in shopping_list:
        print(item)
else:
    print("No items found in the input.")
```

Comment: Please what does `text_to_fraction(quantity_text)` do? Can we see the code in the `text_to_fraction(quantity_text)` function?

Comment: done i put the whole code

Comment: The problem is that the regexp only looks for a one-word quantity before `of {keyword}`. So it just matches `half`, not `three and half`. You need to make the pattern match multiple words and then split it up to parse it.